# c# using the Codekicker.BBCode to convert lists to html

Tags: c#, bbcode

I trying to convert bbcode to html in c#.

I am currently using code found at http://bbcode.codeplex.com/

I would expect bbcode like:

```
[list][*]one[*]two[/list]
```

To be turned into:

```
<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul>
```

Instead I get:

```
<ul><li>one<li>two</li></li></ul>
```

which does not look like valid html to me.

One comment on the site here http://bbcode.codeplex.com/workitem/9656 seems not to do anything   different in the version I am using (CodeKicker.BBCode-Parser-5.0), although there is an extra boolean parameter in the sample code that my version does not accept.

Has anybody had any luck with this converter, or is there a better one, or is there a way to get this to output valid html? for example, I can get it to output:

```
<ul><li>one<li>two</ul>
```

but it looks dodgy to me (but I think it validates).

Answer (score 4):

The parser supports different styles of nesting for different use cases. The syntax you entered is incorrectly nested, but the parser can deal with that if it is correctly configured.

This should get you started:

```
new BBCodeParser(ErrorMode.ErrorFree, null, new[]
        {
            new BBTag("list", "<ul>", "</ul>", true, true),
            new BBTag("*", "<li>", "</li>", true, false),
        });
```

Also note, that there is a `BBTagClosingStyle` enum that is accepted by the `BBTag` constructor. Try `BBTagClosingStyle.LeafElementWithoutContent` if the above code does not work. The source code has the following comment: `leaf elements have no content - they are closed immediately` which sounds promising.

This code snippet is for the 1.0 version but future versions have generally maintained compatibility.

Comment: thanks, but I think new BBTag("*", "<li>", "</li>", true, false) is the default, and LeafElementWithoutContent seems to close the li immediately (placing any content after it)

Comment: I'll look into it. Might take a while. This is a common use case that the library must support.

Comment: it just looks like something the code does not support. according to According to http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html end tags of lis are optional, and I can exclude them by using new BBTag("*", "<li>", "", true, false)

Comment: I guess that solves your issue. I'm still unhappy with it. I find the looseness of HTML disgusting and try to avoid it.

Comment: I don't really like it either, it just seems the easiest way without having to change the source code